# Excel Matching on Multiple Criteria including dynamic ranges based on certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I am trying to find the optimal formula for the following.  I need to pull in a value(*Percent_Number_I_Want*) based on 3 criteria:  the first two are *Group_Lookup* and *Name_Lookup*.  The third condition is Quantity.  This third condition needs to first match on the Group Name and Name and then reference that Quantity_Min column.  It needs to compare the Quantity from the Data tab and find the row where Quantity_Min not bigger than Quantity but is less than or equal to Quantity.

For example, the first record in the Data Tab has Europe, Joe, 1800. I need a formula to search the Lookup Tab to find matches on Joe and Europe (which there are 3 records), then use the Quantity of 1800 to narrow the search to one record. The Joe,Europe combinations have 3 Quantity_Min values: 0, 500, 1000.  Since 1800 is greater than all of them, I want the 1000 record since that's the minimum (**if the quantity were say, 502, I would want the 500 record).  This corresponds to the field *Percent_Number_I_Want* which has a value of 25.3%.  This is the ultimate number I need.  I have manually added the correct percentages in column *Manually Entered Correct Percentages* for data validation purposes.

I can match on the two Name conditions using Index Matches but the Quantity condition is tripping me up.  Also, I would probably structure the data differently, but this is how it currently exists.

[Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oA47g.png)

[Lookup Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe2vq.png)

Comment: You should be using AGGREGATE to find the smallest row number where *Quantity_Min* is `<=` *Quantity*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this at the top of the *Percentage* column in the *Data* table and fill down.

```
=INDEX(Lookup!D:D, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW($2:$99)/((Lookup!A$2:A$99=A2)*(Lookup!B$2:B$99=B2)*(Lookup!C$2:C$99<=C2)), 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- An array (CSE) Formula in cell `R2`:

  ```
  {=IF(MIN(IF(Lookup!J$2:J$20=O2,IF(Lookup!K$2:K$20=P2,IF(Lookup!L$2:L$20<=Q2,Lookup!M$2:M$20))))=0,"",(MIN(IF(Lookup!J$2:J$20=O2,IF(Lookup2!K$2:K$20=P2,IF(Lookup!L$2:L$20<=Q2,Lookup!M$2:M$20))))))}
  ```
- *Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.*
- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*